# Difference between become and become_user in Ansible

Tags: ansible, root, ansible-2.x

Recently I started digging into Ansible and writing my own playbooks. However, I have a troubles with understanding difference between `become` and `become_user`. 
As I understand it `become_user` is something similar to `su <username>`, and `become` means something like `sudo su` or "perform all commands as a sudo user". But sometimes these two directives are mixed.

Could you explain the correct meaning of them?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

`become_user` defines the user which is being used for [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html).

`become` simply is a flag to either activate or deactivate the same.

Here are three examples which should make it clear:

1. This task will be executed as `root`, because `root` is the default user for privilege escalation:

   ```yaml
   - do: something
     become: true
   ```
2. This task will be executed as user `someone`, because the user is explicitly set:

   ```yaml
   - do: something
     become: true
     become_user: someone
   ```
3. This task will not do anything with `become_user`, because `become` is not set and defaults to `false`/`no`:

   ```yaml
   - do: something
     become_user: someone
   ```

   ...unless `become` was set to `true` on a higher level, e.g. a block, include, the playbook or globally via group or host-vars.

Here is an example with a [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html):

```yaml
- become: true
  block:
    - do: something
      become_user: someone

    - do: something

    - do: something
      become: false
      become_user: someone

    - do: something
      become: false
```

The 1st is ran as user `someone`, the 2nd as `root`. The 3rd and 4th tasks have `become` explicitly disabled, so they will be ran as the user who executed the playbook.

> As I understand it become_user is something similar to su , and become means something like sudo su or "perform all commands as a sudo user".

The default `become_method` is `sudo`, so `sudo do something` or `sudo -u <become_user> do something`

<sub><sup>Fineprint: Of course "*do: something*" is pseudocode. Put your actual Ansible module there.</sup></sub>

Comment: So if I want to enable privilege escalation for tasks in playbook I can set become: True once before I define tasks, and afterwards just use become_user whenever I want, right?

Comment: That depends on what you mean with "once before". If you set `become` on a single task, it only is active for that single task. If you want to set `become` for multipel tasks you need to set it on a higher level. You could use [blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) or [includes](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) for this or set in on your role.

Comment: @udondan i am getting the error while using your point no 2. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 16):

1. `become: yes` = `sudo`
       `become_user: user_name` = `sudo -u user_name`
2. `become: yes`
   `become_user: root` is equivalent of `become: yes`

this [link](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/ansible-sudo-ansible-become-example/) is explaining the difference clearly.

Comment: This answer is potentially misleading. If become=yes, then become_user can be used to override the default user. But used on its own, become_user has no effect.

Comment: Can you explain further? @BenAveling it's a little confusing on what you are trying to say.

Comment: Unless "become: yes" is set, setting "become_user" does nothing.

Comment: Yes. How is my answer misleading? 

Comment: because you've separated become:yes from become_user: making it look like you're saying "become_user: root is equivalent of become: yes"

Comment: The link mentioned in the answer should explain everything, as it is very clear. I understood the difference by reading the link.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to run a batch of task with sudo, I often use an include_task statement.
It also helps a lot to keep a large playbook split up in parts.
For example

```
 - name: prepare task x
   include_tasks: x-preparation.yml
   when: condition is true
   args:
     apply:
       become: yes
```

This is also a handy approach when using tags:

```
  - name: execute tasks x
     include_tasks: x-execution.yml
     args:
       apply:
         tags: exec
     tags:
     - exec
```

Important is that you need to put a tag on the include_tasks statement as well
Hope this is helpful for anyone

Answer (score 0):

Become yes will make run the code block as root user by default.
If you add become_user: "user1" along with become: yes then current code block will run as user1.