# ansible: run role as a different user

Tags: ansible, devops

I have two roles that run in a playbook, one that creates a user and the other which runs through a series of tasks that I want to run as the newly created user on the server.

The playbook is written as follows:

```yaml
- hosts: centos
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false
  become: true

  roles:
  - ../roles/user_setup
  - ../roles/tasks
```

Let's say the user created from the `user_setup` role is called `user1`: I basically want the role named `tasks` to run as `user1`. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38290143/difference-between-become-and-become-user-in-ansible) almost provides you a solution. You can use something like:

```yaml
- hosts: centos
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: false

  roles:
  - role: ../roles/user_setup
    become: true

  - role: ../roles/tasks
    become: true
    become_user: user1
```

If you want to connect directly as `user1` (rather than escalating to it), you can replace the latest role call with:

```yaml
  - role: ../roles/tasks
    become: false
    remote_user: user1
```

Comment: yeah, i figured it would be something along this lines but I just didnt know what the syntax would be. Thanks.